# how to solve zend_translate problem with some keywords?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-translate

i am using zend_translate class (ini adaptor) for my multi language site.

but when i use some keywords in my language files it produce error. for example (yes, no keywords).

sample language file entries which produce error:

yes=native language yes

no=native language no

how do i solve this problem?

thx in advance.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. try rewording it or posting what code you have because as it is I cannot help you. But I have used Zend_Translate plenty.

Comment: What error message are you getting? What is a keyword in your context? What kind of translation files are you using?

Comment: i mean that zend_translate have problem with some special words like 'yes','no'.
when i use these words in my language.ini file to translate, it raises these errors:

Warning: Error parsing E:\work\web\tadbir/application/admin/languages/fa.ini on line 1 in C:\Program Files\xampp\php\Zend\Translate\Adapter\Ini.php on line 69

Warning: array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array in C:\Program Files\xampp\php\Zend\Translate\Adapter\Ini.php on line 74

Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in C:\Program Files\xampp\php\Zend\Translate\Adapter.php on line 477

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.sourcecreation.html)

> INI files have several restrictions. If a value in the ini file
>   contains any non-alphanumeric characters it needs to be enclosed in
>   double-quotes ("). There are also reserved words which must not be
>   used as keys for ini files. These include: NULL, yes, no, TRUE, and
>   FALSE. Values NULL, no and FALSE results in "", yes and TRUE results
>   in 1. Characters {}|&~![()" must not be used anywhere in the key and
>   have a special meaning in the value. Do not use them as it will
>   produce unexpected behaviour.